# How to get table size in splice machine?

Tags: sql, splice-machine

I am not able to fetch the size of my table in Splice Machine database.

This view `SYS.SYSTABLESTATISTICS` is not returning any value.  However i have tables and data in those tables.

```
Select * from SYS.SYSTABLESTATISTICS;
```

I expect the output to be the size of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run analyze on your table?
Need to run this for there to be data in systablstatistics.

Comment: thank you. that helped. i was able to get the table size after analyzing the table.